# Java Android getContentResolver().query for specific Camera folder to get cursor in Android API level <= 28 devices

Tags: java, android, mediastore, android-9.0-pie

I want to get the last taken image from the Camera folder. I don't want to get last screenshot or anything else. I just want to take the last image of the Camera folder.

This code works, but if there is a folder named "Cameras" or "xxx..Camera..xxx", the program also fetches the data of those folders.

```
 cursor = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                new String[] {"%Camera%"},
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

But I don't want to query the folders whose name contains the "Camera" character sequence. I just want to query for Camera default save folder. In my case /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera.

Comment: Try `new String[] {"%/Camera/%"}`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works. But is there any other way to get camera default saving directory? @blackapps

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your code does not get a directory but files in a directory.

Comment: Sorry for that. But I want to ask how can I get Camera default saving directory? In my case path of camera default saving directory is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera @blackapps

Comment: Do all devices have the same path? @blackapps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can query for specific directory by using

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
```

Now my code works like this and without any problems:

```
cursor = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? ",
                new String[] {"Camera"},
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```